# Angular post send fail

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, post, jersey

I have a problem with sending post to server. I am using jersey.
In angular I made it like this:

```
services.factory('UserService', function($resource) {

return $resource('rest/user/:action', {},
        {
            authenticate: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {'action' : 'authenticate'},
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            },
        }
    );
});

$scope.login = function() {
        UserService.authenticate($.param({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}), function(authenticationResult) {
            var authToken = authenticationResult.token;
            $rootScope.authToken = authToken;
            if ($scope.rememberMe) {
                $cookieStore.put('authToken', authToken);
            }
            UserService.get(function(user) {
                $rootScope.user = user;
                $location.path("/");
            });
        });
    };
```

On the server side I have:

```
@Path("authenticate")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TokenTransfer authenticate(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password)
{
    //authentication
}
```

And when I click send button I get POST on rest/user/authenticate failed with status 403.
It was working well since I have changed jersey to jersey-spring3 to let it compatibile with spring 4.

Where can be problem?

Jersey dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
            </dependency>

              <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does spring-security block the request? Maybe some default configuration have changed with the spring upgrade.

Comment: Maybe, but how can I check it? I have `<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/authenticate" access="permitAll" />` in spring-security configuration. Adding metod manifestly to POST not helping.

Comment: Enable the debug logging of spring and if it doesn't give a clue then you need to debug throught the spring code starting with the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: can you try to replace "params" with "data" ?

Comment: Now I realized that it worked with spring 3.2, I have migrated a little time before to spring 4.1 and security 4.0 so probably its configuration...

Comment: @ThomasP1988 behaviour not changed